VirtualBox guest reveals real host name
I have set up two virtual machines in VirtualBox for malware analysis: 1) a Windows VM (FlareVM) and 2) REMnux. Both VMs are configured with a Host-only adapter.
I've verified all settings multiple times, and the VMs can communicate with each other while remaining isolated from my network. When I attempt to ping from the VM to my host machine, the request is denied and of course block from internet.
However, I've encountered one issue: Wireshark logs are showing the name of my real host. I’ve tried several solutions to address this, including disabling APIPA on my host, blocking traffic at the firewall on the VM, disabling Function Discovery Provider on the VM, and turning off IPv6.
The attached photo illustrates the issue, with the red square highlighting the name of my real host:
Adapter
DHCP Server

Is there a reason you chose Host Only for the adaptor instead of Internal Network? If you don't want your host to be there then using internal would only allow the VMs to communicate to each other on the Internal virtual box network.
